# Convert single-element sub-lists to normal elements

Tags: python, sublist

I have the following list:

```
[['identificator', [6036971], [1112221]], ['gender', ['Male'], ['Female']]]
```

How can I turn the single element lists into normal elements, like this?

```
[['identificator', 6036971, 1112221], ['gender', 'Male', 'Female']]
```

I'm using this as input for csv.writer.writerow, and I get the brackets printed as a string :-/

The code this happens with is here https://github.com/TheChymera/E2att/commit/4dd5e391b3ec7a4d630cef7c8c8fa803ede3e808#quest.py - the variable I'm having trouble with gets created as such:

```
def lefilter(keep=None):
data, filters, _ = get_data()
mask = filters[:,-1] == keep
lefilter = filters[mask][:,:-1]
value = data[:,lefilter.astype(np.bool)[0]]
if keep != 'gender':
    value = value.astype(np.integer)
return value
```

Comment: What do you want the list to end up as?

Comment: either a list of lists (just one sublist step) or a 2d numpy array.

Comment: Show us the output you expect from the list in your question.

Comment: [['identificator', 6036971, 1112221], ['gender', 'Male', 'Female']]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by using this code:

```
for ixr, row in enumerate(leresults):
    for ixe, el in enumerate(row):
        if len(el)==1:
            leresults[ixr][ixe] = el[0]
```

I'm sure there'S a more elegant way to do this, but for now I'm happy it works!

Answer (score 0):

You know the `itertools` module?

`itertools.chain.from_iterable(your_list_here)`.  Wrap it in a list if you're not iterating over it.

Comment: I tried print itertools.chain.from_iterable(leresults) in quest.py, but I get only <itertools.chain object at 0x11af790>

Comment: You need to make it a list, first.  Just do `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(your_list))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
map(lambda x: x[0] if isinstance(x, list) else x, list_item)
```

Comment: how can I use that command? I tried
print map(lambda x: x[0] if isinstance(x, list) else x, leresults)
in quest.py but it will only list the first sublist of the list. What values should I substitute by what?